# Modify my tcolorbox

Tags: fontsize, tcolorbox

I am trying to make a color box in which I wish to add some words.

How can I make the word "ap" centered? Even please suggest to me any other ways in order to make my box attractive.

One more question how to increase the font size of the words.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=ab, width=.19\linewidth, nobeforeafter]
cab
dab
gab
lab
jab
nab
tab
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `title={\centering ab}` can center your title.

Comment: @Niranjan In `tcolorbox` there is a specific option to center the title: `center title`

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for the information :)

Comment: @Niranjan You're welcome. It is easiest than writing `\centering` every time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To center the title you can use `center title`.

If all the boxes of you document are like this, you may set the options with `\tcbset`, instead of repeating them for any box.

I enlarged a bit the width to avoid `Overfull hbox` warning.

I used `halign=left` to avoid `Underfull hbox` warning.

For the font size, you may use `fonttitle` for the title and `fontupper` for the box.

To align the boxes to the top, use `box align = top`.

Regarding making your box attractive, could you be more specific? There are many way to modify a `tcolobox`. What would you like?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!75!black, width=.20\linewidth, halign=left, nobeforeafter, center title, box align = top, fonttitle=\Huge, fontupper=\Huge}

\begin{document}
Normal text

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=ab]
cab
dab
gab
lab
jab
nab
tab
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=II]
cab
dab
gab
lab
jab
nab
tab
mor
e w
ord
s 
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Suppose i add one more box which contains more word than the first one then how can i make these two boxes equal in top position

Comment: My second box and first box are placed with different top alignment. Please guide me

Comment: Thanks a lot to CarLaTeX .Please help me in my second question

Comment: @Math-Man `box align = top` see my edit

Comment: Wonderful thanks a lot again.